# Printing paths of a graph, list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-theory

Been trying to print all paths of a graph that's defined by the following dictionary

```
graph = {
    "a": [
        {"child": "b", "cost": 5},
        {"child": "e", "cost": 8}
    ],
    "b": [
        {"child": "c", "cost": 7},
        {"child": "f", "cost": 2}
    ],
    "d": [
        {"child": "g", "cost": 3},
    ],
    "e": [
        {"child": "d", "cost": 3},
        {"child": "f", "cost": 6}
    ],
    "f": [
        {"child": "c", "cost": 1},
    ],
    "g": [
        {"child": "h", "cost": 10}
    ],
    "h": [
        {"child": "f", "cost": 4}
    ]
}
def print_all_child_paths(graph, node_name):
    node = graph[node_name]

    if len(node) == 0:
        print("No children under this node")
    else:
        x = 1
        for child_node in node:
            print("Path number " + str(x) + ": ")
            print(node_name + " -> ")

            current_node = child_node

            while current_node["child"] in graph:
                print(current_node["child"] + " -> ")
                current_node = graph[current_node["child"]]

            print("END.")
        x += 1

    print("End of paths")

print_all_child_paths(graph, "a")
```

When I run the function `print_all_child_paths`, I end up with the error `list indices must be integers, not str`.

The compiler points to line 40, which is the while loop definition:
`while current_node["child"] in graph:`

I was confused about the error since the condition for the loop is checking if the key is in the dictionary. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do some `print`s here and there. You will surely be able to track what's happening wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you do `current_node = graph[current_node["child"]]` on the first iteration of the loop, `current_node` becomes a list, because all the values of the `graph` dictionary are lists.

However, right after that your code attempts to do `current_node["child"]` in the condition of the loop, but `current_node`, being a list, cannot be indexed with strings, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Each `node` is a list of dictionaries.  So `current_node` is a list and can only be accessed with a integer index.  You are trying to access it as a dictionary with a key that is a string.  You need to iterate through the node list to get access to each dictionary.

```
for child in current node:
    while child["child"] in graph:
```